# Last version of jChart, JFreeChart, iText, JasperReports that runs with jdk 1.4

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext, jfreechart, jchartfx

I'm going to develop a Web App. with Jdk 1.4 on Weblogic 8 and I need to use jChart, JFreeChart, iText and JasperReport.
Which version of these libraries do I have to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

JasperReports 3.7.1 seems to be the last version for JDK 1.4. I used this tool to check it: http://code.google.com/p/versioncheck/